# How to update all records in a table with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

### Solution

```
foreach($request->all() as $record){
    EventViews::query()->updateOrCreate(['id'=>$record['id']], $record);
}
```

### Question

How do I update a whole table by passing a `request array`? It should update existing rows and create new ones if `id` doesn't exist. If possible without having to `loop` over the whole table.

Attempts that don't work:

```
EventViews::query()->updateOrCreate($request->all());
```

.

```
DB::transaction(function ($request) {
    foreach ($request->all() as $record) {
        EventViews::updateOrCreate($record);
    }
});
```

.

```
$model = new EventViews($request->all());
$model->fill($request->all())->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your request payload looks something like

```
records[]=[id=1,name=foo,description=foo,c=1]&
records[]=[id=2,name=bar,description=bar,c=1]&
...
```

you could loop over it like:

```
$input = $request->input('records');
foreach($input as $record){
    EventViews::query()->updateOrCreate(['id'=>$record['id']],$record);
}
```

**if your request looks like:**

```
1=[name=foo,description=foo,c=1]&
2=[name=bar,description=bar,c=1]&
...
```

where the parameter name is the id, then you could use:

```
$input = $request->input();
foreach($input as $key => $record){
    EventViews::query()->updateOrCreate(['id'=>$key],$record);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

updateOrCreate receives 2 parameters, the first is the constrains and the second is the data. 
I don't know your request structure, but it's good practice verify it before throwing it into your database. 
Example: 
`Model::query()->updateOrCreate(` 
  `['my_column' => $request->input('my_column')],` 
  `[*array of column/values of what should be updated*]` 
`)]`

If exists a Model with given my_column value, it will update it's value with the associative array passed on the second argument, otherwise it will create a new entry.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method :

```
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```

or

```
Flight::upsert([
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
    ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
], ['departure', 'destination'], ['price']);
```

for get more information see this link:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts